# Android: Updating widget only when it is visible on the home screen

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I have seen several posts in SO about this (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416782/android-how-update-widget-often-but-only-when-it-is-visible) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076769/updating-a-widget-only-when-device-is-on-and-widget-is-visible-on-home-screen)) but they're rather old so I will ask again:

I have a home screen widget that I would like to update ONLY when the widget is enabled and added to the screen AND it is visible for the user (e.g. that the widget is in the current desktop screen).

It this possible? And if it isn't, is there any possible work around?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, you still have no way of knowing whether an app widget is currently visible. You should know whether it is added to the home screen, as there are `AppWidgetProvider` callbacks for that.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare